# USB Device not Recognised - Custom Wattuino Nanite 841

Tags: attiny, hardware

What I have done:

I have made a custom Nanite 841 which uses an ATTINY841 microcontroller. 
I have used the schematics from Wattuino to design my circuit, my PCB was made using a router with all excess copper removed. 
I have built the circuit and have ensured that every component and track does not short circuit. 
I have successfully uploaded the Wattuino bootloader using ISP.

The Problem:

The problem that I am getting is when the microcontroller is connected to any computer I get an error message saying...

> "USB device not recognised"

The device status shows this...

> Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems.
>   (Code 43)
>
> A request for the USB device descriptor failed.

I hope you can help as this is a bit of a bummer after just building my new device. Thank you for your time.

[image: PCB Layout of my circuit]

[image: Schematic of my circuit]

Comment: Is it a double sided board? I don't see any traces going from the USB to the VCC and GND pins of the attiny. Without power the chip won't run (per see)

Comment: -1 Your PCB does not match your schematic.  In addition to the ground problem,  it shows a 14 pin IC while the MCU you show has pins up to 16 and then a pin 20.  This question is not answerable due to its self contradictions, so it needs to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Github: micronucleus/micronucleus](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus)
 :

> Windows machines will need to install the libusb drivers found in the /windows_drivers folder.  Clean Micronucleus devices without uploaded userprogram will not time out and allow sufficient time for proper driver installation. Linux and OS X do not require custom drivers.

Make sure you have installed the device drivers.

---

Also you need to attempt an upload *shortly* after reset:

> The bootloader allows uploading of new firmware via USB. In its usual configuration it is invoked at device reset and will identify to the host computer. If no communication is initiated by the host machine within a given time, the bootloader will time out and enter the user program, if one is present.

---

See the troubleshooting page [Code 43: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725873%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

---

You should be able to use a spare Uno or similar device to check the chip response. See [Sketch to detect Atmega chip types](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11633).

Possibly you have the "divide clock by 8" fuse set. You could clear that if so.